# How to heat water using a magnifying glass?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, temperature, estimation

If I want to heat a mug of water using a magnifying glass or glasses, how to I work out the size of glass needed, how many are needed to do the task in a set time?

Comment: interesting premise, but how do you propose to deal with water refracting most of the light? you can see through water because it does not absorb a lot of the visible spectrum

Comment: There are lots of factors that make it hard to get make an accurate estimate, including those already mentioned.  Unless you're in the tropics, you will be shining the light on the surface of the water from an angle, which affects the reflection.   If you do the experiment, let us know what you find.

Answer (score 1):

The magnifying glass only bundles the solar radiation and energy flux to a smaller cross section. Thus a magnifying glass can only then be advantageous for the heating of your mug in the sun when its area is substantially larger than the cross section of your mug. Otherwise direct solar heating should be better. You should keep also in mind that there is a loss of light transmission through the glass due to reflection and absorption.

Answer (score 0):

As Cursed has pointed out in the comments, water is transparent, so it doesn't really work out that way.  On the other hand, you could try aiming the magnifying glass at the inner surface of the mug to allow the water to gain heat via conduction and convection.

As to how to speed up the heating, a larger magnifying glass would work better.  The equation is given by $$r_{image}=\frac{r_{sun}}{d_{sun}}f$$
Where $r_{image}$ is the radius of the image of the sun formed, and $r_{sun}$ is the radius of the sun, $695700$km.  $d_{sum}$ is the distance to the sun, $149600000$km and $f$ the focal length.  Hence $\frac{r_{sun}}{d_{sun}}$ is about $4.6\times 10^{-3}$.  In addition, the intensity of the sunlight is around $1kWm^{-2}$.  From here you can probably work it out.

Comment: Thanks guys for the answers.  I should have added that I would direct the light to the metal mug which I suppose should be black.  This is for a friend who travels in Central and Northern Africa and a solar heating panel will probably be an easier option

Answer (score 0):

A portable solar heater for a mug would use either a Fresnel lens or a concave reflector instead of a magnifying glass.
Ideally, it would be foldable and very lightweight. The optical quality does not need to be very good since a mug is fairly large.

Probably something like a spring wire loop holding a half-aluminized Mylar balloon would do the trick:
[image]